# Removing item from state object in react (strange rendering)

Tags: reactjs, rendering, state

I created a project in Reactjs where I have a list of names that I want to display in a custom list. Each item has a button to delete the item, however whenever I click the button, the last item is removed from the list no matter which list item I click.

I have already tried to debug my code using the js-console but that made the problem even stranger since the console displays the correct state wheras the component "List" renders a list item which is no longer present in the state object

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ListItem'
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class List extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [
                {name: 'Tobi'},
                {name: 'Maxi'},
                {name: 'David'},
                {name: 'Peter'},
            ]
        }
    }

    removeItem = (id) => {
        let few = this.state.items;
        few.splice(id,1);
        //console.log(this.state.items);   
        this.setState({items: few}, function(){
            console.log(this.state.items.map((item) => item.name));
            this.forceUpdate();
        });
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.items.map((item, i) => <ListItem name={item.name} key={i} id={i} remove={this.removeItem}/>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ListItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name,
            id: this.props.id
        }
    }

    test = () => {
        this.props.remove(this.state.id);
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <li>{this.state.name} <button onClick={() => this.test()}>click me</button></li>
        );
    }
}

export default ListItem;
```

As is said i excpected the right list item to be removed however it is always the last item that isnt rendered anymore even though the state object says different.

Comment: that was an interesting problem. Even I am seeing something similar. it could be because of the key being passed

Comment: check this out changing the key. it works, not sure if this is the expected behaviour or not https://codesandbox.io/s/yq8k5ywwo1

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be working as I intended, but can you explain why it doesn't work with the index as id?

Comment: That's because of key. If the key doesn't change react assumes that the element didn't change. Key should be the value which is the unique thing for an object. That's y eslint gives an error while giving array indices as keys.

Comment: upvote the comment if it answers you.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're using an array index as a `key`. When you first render the ListItems you have :

- ListItem name={'Tobi'} key={0}
- ListItem name={'Maxi'} key={1}
- ListItem name={'David'} key={2}
- ListItem name={'Peter'} key={3}

Let's say you removed the item with index 1, all other items will shift index:

- ListItem name={'Tobi'} key={0}
- ListItem name={'David'} key={1}
- ListItem name={'Peter'} key={2}

React will only compare the keys, and because the only difference between the first and second render is that the item with key={3} is not present, this is the item that will be removed from the dom.

Also avoid mutating the state directly (`few.splice(id,1)`), and try to avoid `this.forceUpdate()`

Try using an actual id in your data :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tobi" },
        { id: 2, name: "Maxi" },
        { id: 3, name: "David" },
        { id: 4, name: "Peter" }
      ]
    };
  }

  removeItem = id => {
    let few = this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !==id);
    //console.log(this.state.items);
    this.setState({ items: few }, function() {
      console.log(this.state.items.map(item => item.name));
      //this.forceUpdate();
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map((item, i) => (
            <ListItem
              name={item.name}
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              remove={this.removeItem}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.name,
      id: this.props.id
    };
  }

  test = () => {
    this.props.remove(this.state.id);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        {this.state.name} <button onClick={() => this.test()}>click me</button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```